# Automatically find out proper value of 'pos' for plotting axis labels

Tags: r, plot

In the last line of the example below, I had to manually try a couple of different values for `pos` before I found the 'correct' value that was just outside of the `labels` that had already been plotted in the previous line. Is there a way to find out that proper value of `pos` automatically?

```
dev.off()
windows(width = 8, height = 6)
par(mai = c(0.3, 2.5, 0.3, 0.3)) #bottom, left, top and right
set.seed(42)
plot(rnorm(15,10,1),rnorm(15,10,1), type = "p",
     ylim = c(5,15), xlim = c(5,15), xlab = "", ylab = "",
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", yaxs="i", xaxs="i")
axis(2, at = c(5,10,15), labels = c("This one", "Particularly long one", "two"), las = 2)
axis(2, at = 10, pos = 2, labels = "Y Axis Label", font = 2, tick = FALSE, cex.axis = 1.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab `par(usr)[1]` and subtract the `strwidth` of your long label to get the position:

```
dev.off()
windows(width = 8, height = 6)
par(mai = c(0.3, 2.5, 0.3, 0.3)) #bottom, left, top and right
set.seed(42)
plot(rnorm(15, 10, 1),rnorm(15, 10, 1), type = "p",
     ylim = c(5, 15), xlim = c(5, 15), xlab = "", ylab = "",
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", yaxs= "i", xaxs= "i")
axis(2, at = c(5, 10, 15),
     labels = c("This one", "Particularly long one", "two"), las = 2)

# get the position based on the long string width and par('usr')[1]
pos <- par('usr')[1] - strwidth("Particularly long one")

axis(2, at = 10, pos = pos,
     labels = "Y Axis Label", font = 2, tick = FALSE, cex.axis = 1.5)
```

[image]

Of course, if you resize the image interactively after this, all bets are off.

Comment: @DarshanBaral Sure, some mix of `max`, `which.max`, or `which` should be able to help.  `max(strwidth(label_variable))` will get the maximum and `which(strwidth(label_variable) == max(strwidth(label_variable))` will tell you which one(s) are the maximum(s).